# Compound key that only allows nulls if they are null in the referenced table

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint

I want to create a compound foreign key constraint that only allows a null value in one of the columns if there is a matching row with a null value in the referenced table. Additionally, the referencing-field combinations should not be required to be unique. I'm working in PostgreSQL 9.4, in case that gives me a solution that wouldn't otherwise exist.

For example, let's say I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  a_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  b_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,name text NOT NULL
  ,a_id integer REFERENCES a (a_id)
);

CREATE TABLE c (
  c_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,name text NOT NULL
  ,b_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES b (b_id)
  ,a_id integer
);
```

Now suppose that `a` has data

```
a_id | name
-----+----------
   1 | 'First A'
```

and `b` has data

```
b_id | name       | a_id
-----+------------+-----
   1 | 'First B'  |    1
   2 | 'Second B' | NULL
```

I would like to alter `c` (and other tables as needed) so that the following will **all succeed**,

```
INSERT INTO c (b_id, a_id, name) VALUES (1, 1, 'First C');
INSERT INTO c (b_id, a_id, name) VALUES (2, NULL, 'Second C');
INSERT INTO c (b_id, a_id, name) VALUES (1, 1, 'Another 1-1 C');
```

but both of these will **fail**,

```
INSERT INTO c (b_id, a_id, name) VALUES (1, NULL, 'Bad C one');  --b=1 must have a=1
INSERT INTO c (b_id, a_id, name) VALUES (2, 1, 'Bad C two');  --b=2 must have a=NULL
```

---

If `b` and `c` did not allow `a_id` to be null, then I could just

```
ALTER TABLE b
  ADD UNIQUE (b_id, a_id);
ALTER TABLE c
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (b_id, a_id)
  REFERENCES b (b_id, a_id);
```

With the null `a_id` values though, this allows the first bad insert to succeed, because the null value in the `a_id` column isn't checked against the value of any rows in `b`.

I also tried using `MATCH FULL`, but this prevents the insertion of null values in the `a_id` column entirely, even though it is nullable, since `b_id` cannot also be null.

---

What is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: No, not possible with nulls. Normalize the database, don't use nullable columns, if you want to have referencial integrity.

Comment: But I wonder, why do you need the `a_id` in the `c` table? What's the problem i f you remove it - and reference only `b (b_id)` ?

Comment: If `a` is a user table, then I want each user to see all rows of `b` that have an `a_id` that is either null or that matches the user's id. `c` contains separate objects that each require one `b`, but which should not be allowed to reference rows of `b` that belong to a different user.

Comment: Is there a better way to be accomplishing the goal of having some rows visible to all, and others only to one user? I couldn't think of another way that didn't involve a second nearly identical table for each of `b` and `c`.

Comment: OK but you haven't answered. Why removing `c (a_id)` doesn't solve your problem? You can always find the relative user (a_id) by joining to `b`.

Comment: You're right of course, thank you. I'm not sure what I was thinking yesterday! I was conflating two different requirements, and ended up with something that doesn't work properly for either -- I want to be able to store a `c` that belongs to a specific `a`, but which uses a `b` that is public. That's why I first thought to add `c.a_id` I guess, but then I just went the wrong direction from there and somehow ended up asking a question that explicitly disallows that...

Comment: Anyway, if you want to add a reference or a little more discussion, I'm happy to accept an answer that shows the answer is "no".